# how can I manage services running in freebsd jail

Tags: freebsd, dovecot, jails, qmail, rspamd

I've inherited some systems that run on freebsd and inside jails.  Basically the services running are old versions of qmail, spamd, dovecot, etc.  None of the versions are up to date or even maintainable any more.

At present we can't move from these systems but I would at least like to be able to troubleshoot them.

My question:

Normally I would be Able to run service qmail status for example and get some info about the top level process.  How do I do this inside a jail.  In the case of the qmail process I can use qmailctl but what would be the equivalent for spamd or dovecot ?

also how do you go about troubleshooting these types of services the logs don't really give a very good steer on what could be going wrong.

Comment: Start with the man pages for `jls(8)` and `jexec(8)`.  Use `jls` to query the name or ID number of the jail you're interested in, and then you can use `jexec` to launch a shell within that particular jail.  Once you're in, it's just like managing any other qmail/spamd/dovecot installation. Also, the `service(8)` utility itself is jail-aware.  [See the man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?service(8)) and note the `-j` command line switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# jls


JID  IP Address      Hostname                      Path
     1  127.0.0.2       ports12.localhost             /SPACE/jails/ports12
     2  127.0.0.3       py37jail.localhost            /SPACE/jails/py37jail
```

OK now I know what jails are running. I'm going to `logon` as `root` as root is understood in the `ports12.localhost` [jail(8)](https://manpage.me/?jail)

```
jexec -l -U root 1

root@ports12:~ #
```

Now that you know how to get in. You can do whatever you like, as you would normally do on the/a host system. Nearly **every** command is available, as would be on the Host system. When you're done. You can simply type `exit`, or use the key combination of `^d` That is; the Ctrl+d keys. See also: [jexec(8)](https://manpage.me/?jexec), [jls(8)](https://manpage.me/?jls), and [jail.conf(5)](https://manpage.me/?jail.conf)